# How to Assign jsp variable to html element

Tags: jsp

i am facing a problem with this jsp scriptlet i don't know why its not running it
gives Null Pointer exception
  what could be the reason:

```
//p is a product object which i previously stored in session as //attribute     
<%  Product  p     =     (Product)request.getAttribute("product");%>


for (var row =1; row <= 1; row++) {
   for (var col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
      if(row == 1 && col == 1){
        $('#tbl').children().children()[row].children[col].innerHTML =  <%=p.getProductCode()%>
      }
   }
}

//this line below is trying to set table's cell value to the one of properties of that product object
$('#tbl').children().children()[row].children[col].innerHTML = <%= p.getProductCode()%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid scriptlets altogether, rather easily.  Even if the product is not null, I would expect javascript errors from your innerHTML assignments due to the absence of quotes around the values, which are string literals on the page.  If the `NullPointerException` continues, please post the code with which you are setting the product object into the request.

```
for (var row =1; row <= 1; row++) {
   for (var col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
      if(row == 1 && col == 1){
        $('#tbl').children().children()[row].children[col].innerHTML = '${requestScope.product.productCode}';
      }
   }
}

$('#tbl').children().children()[row].children[col].innerHTML = '${requestScope.product.productCode}';
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason can be that `Product p` is null, check it by output `<%= p %>`.

Comment: instead of <%= p.getProductCode()%> i have also tried 
<%= ((Product)request.getAttribute("product")).getProductCode()%>
i am sure i have saved this as "product" in the request object
BTW when i run it,it doesn't render html it gives error directly @Alex